# How to style each element individually based on their boolean property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have `DATA` array in which i store objects that contain sentences and answers. Each answer has its `isCorrect` prop.

How do I check answer correctnes on button click?

After button click, correct  answers should make `<select>` tag border change to green and incorrect or undefined to red.

[image: Edit nameless-star-s8xl0f]

Parent component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState();
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleValueChange = (isCorrect) => {
    setIsCorrect(isCorrect);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {DATA.map((sentence, index) => (
        <Sentence isCorrect={isChecked ? isCorrect : null}>
          <span>
            {index + 1}. {sentence.sentenceFirstPart}
          </span>
          <select>
            {sentence.answerOptions.map((option) => (
              <option
                onChange={() => handleValueChange(option.answerText)}
                value={option.answerText}
              >
                {option.answerText}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <span>{sentence.sentenceSecondPart}</span>
        </Sentence>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setIsChecked(true)}>Check</button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Styled components:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;

  button {
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    width: 6rem;
  }
`;

export const Sentence = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  select {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-color: ${({ isCorrect }) =>
      isCorrect ? "green" : !isCorrect && isCorrect !== undefined ? "red" : ""};
  }
`;
```

Test data:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    sentenceFirstPart: "It takes a lot of",
    sentenceSecondPart: "to learn how to waterski properly",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "attempt", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "effort", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "trial", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "try", isCorrect: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    sentenceFirstPart: "It was Thomas Edison who ",
    sentenceSecondPart: "electricity",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "detected", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "invented", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "found", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "discovered", isCorrect: false }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: While linking to an external code demonstration is ok (and often helpful!), your answer should include all of the source code required for a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `isCorrect` would need to record result of each questions and `handleValueChange` should probably be called on change of `select` to update the values in `isCorrect`.

Forked example with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/question-check-iscorrect-2ulopc?file=/src/App.js)

Here `isCorrect` is updated as an object to save result of each question:

```
const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState({});
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

const handleValueChange = (value, index) => {
  setIsCorrect((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [index]: value === "true" ? true : false,
  }));
};
```

`handleValueChange` modified to pass `value` of `option` and `index` of the question, so `isCorrect` can be updated accordingly:

```
<Wrapper>
  {DATA.map((sentence, index) => (
    <Sentence isChecked={isChecked} isCorrect={isCorrect[index]} key={index}>
      <span>
        {index + 1}. {sentence.sentenceFirstPart}
      </span>
      <select onChange={(e) => handleValueChange(e.target.value, index)}>
        {sentence.answerOptions.map((option, index) => (
          <option value={option.isCorrect} key={index}>
            {option.answerText}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <span>{sentence.sentenceSecondPart}</span>
    </Sentence>
  ))}
  <button onClick={() => setIsChecked(true)}>Check</button>
</Wrapper>
```

In styled `Sentence` the `select` could take both `isChecked` and `isCorrect` (for this question) as conditions to set the `border-color`.

```
export const Sentence = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  select {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-color: ${({ isChecked, isCorrect }) =>
      !isChecked ? "currentColor" : isCorrect ? "green" : "red"};
  }
`
```